# How do I add two spf records?

Tags: dns, smtp, spf, zoho

I'm using Zoho mail with my domain name. I also use an SMTP service with my domain name to send newsletters.

In order for Zoho to work properly I am required to add an spf record to my domain DNS. The SMTP service also requires my to add spf record.

My question is can I add multiple spf record to a domain name? If not is it possible to somehow combine the two?

These are the recorde I need to use:

```
v=spf1 include:zoho.com ~all

v=spf1 mx a ip4:91.82.206.0/24 ip4:91.83.103.0/24 ~all
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two, but you can combine them, like this:

```
v=spf1 ip4:91.82.206.0/24 ip4:91.83.103.0/24 mx a include:zoho.com ~all
```

It's best practice to put literal IPs first as they are the fastest for receivers to check.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have multiple SPF records on a single domain. Otherwise, SPF will return PermError.

An SPF record is a TXT record in the DNS starting exactly with "v=spf1", followed by an array of mechanisms and/or modifiers.

An SPF check starts by fetching all TXT records starting exactly with "v=spf1" on a domain:

- if no such record is found, it returns None;
- if multiple such records are found, it returns PermError.

You would need to add all the mechanisms in 1 SPF record, as mentioned by Synchro.

Learn more here: https://dmarcly.com/blog/can-i-have-multiple-spf-records-on-my-domain